# Most succinct way to populate an MVC Dropdown from database with composite value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to populate a dropdownlist from a database, and I'm looking for the most succinct way to do it.

I've gotten this to work:

```
viewModel.CrewList = db.Crew.AsNoTracking().Select(x => new 
SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.CrewID,
    Text = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName
}).ToList();
```

I think it's kind of verbose though, I don't really like lists of SelectListItems.

Normally I'd try something like this:

```
viewModel.CrewList = new SelectList(db.Crew.ToList(), "CrewId", "Name");
```

However, it errors when I try getting it to work with the composite value:

```
viewModel.CrewList = new SelectList(db.Crew.ToList(), "CrewId", "FirstName + ' ' + LastName");
```

This one also produces strange results in the dropdown (for both anon objects and SelectListItems):

```
viewModel.CrewList = new SelectList(db.CREW_EVW.Select(c => new 
{ Value = c.CrewID, Text = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName })
.ToList());
```

What's the best way to do this, in the future?

Answer (score 2):

> > What's the best way to do this, in the future?

```
viewModel.CrewList = db.Crew.AsNoTracking().Select(x => new 
SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.CrewID,
    Text = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName
}).ToList();
```

But seriously, it's critical that you don't go loading the whole table to populate the list, which your other two methods both do by calling db.Crew.ToList();

If you want to avoid SelectListItems you can pass a collection of anonymous types to SelectList.  EG

```
new SelectList(db.Crew.Select( c => new {c.CrewId, Name=c.FirstName + " " + x.LastName}).ToList());
```

Which is easily refactored into

```
db.Crew.Select( c => new {c.CrewId, Name=c.FirstName + " " + x.LastName} ).ToSelectList();
```

or

```
db.Crew.ToSelectList( c => new {c.CrewId, Name=c.FirstName + " " + x.LastName} );
```

with a simple extension method, like

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<T,W>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, Expression<Func<T,W>> selector) where T:class
{
    return new SelectList(dbSet.AsNoTracking().Select(selector).AsEnumerable());
}
```

or Async

```
public static async Task<SelectList> ToSelectListAsync<T, W>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, Expression<Func<T, W>> selector) where T : class
{
    var results = await dbSet.AsNoTracking().Select(selector).ToListAsync();
    return new SelectList(results);
}
```

Comment: The only thing I dislike about this answer is that given the ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework usage, the `async` versions of the methods should be used